# Authentication using Fetch

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, loopbackjs

I'm using Javascript in react. I have a table "users" in my db with a boolean that tells me the type of user (patient, doctor, etc), what I'm trying to do is when I insert a user's code into an auth form in my application front-end, it checks out if the user exists && is not a "patient".If the response is true it have to redirect to another page with a route.

I've tried some code but it redirect  in any case.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { styles }           from './styles.scss';

class HomeView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this); }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}

handleSubmit() {
const { history } = this.props;
if(checkUtente() )
  history.push('/uploadareariservata')  
else
console.log('no pazienti')
   };
 render() {
return (
  <div className={styles}>
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <label>
      Area Riservata:
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="Alphanumeric" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="codice" />
      <br />
      <br/>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Accedi" placeholder="inserire codice" />
  </form>
  </div>
);
}
}

 function checkUtente() {
return fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/UTENTEs?filter={"where":{"is_paziente":false}}', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => true)
.catch(error => false);
} 

export default HomeView;
```

I expect to be redirected to /uploadareariservata if the input exists but it's not a patient.

Comment: can you share  the controller code

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to add a flag.
Example:

```
console.log(checkUtente())
```

I think, fetch return true if you get 2XX response (200, 2001, etc).
Probably, you need to get the data of the response and if exists, redirect to '/uploadareariservata'